# Slide input on hover and stay for few seconds

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

How to open the input box on hover an icon and it should stay open for few seconds then it should automatically slide back to the initial position.

I have tried in css but I need to do this using jquery.

Initially there will be an icon when hover happens then icon should disappear and input box should slide.

Here is the link for the demo what I have tried.

```
.media{
    width:6%;
    background:yellow;
    height:26px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    transition: width 1s;
    -moz-transition: width 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: width 1s; /* Opera */
    -ms-transition: width 1s; /* IE9 (maybe) */
    vertical-align:top;
    overflow:hidden
}
.media:hover{
    width:25%;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aVDgk/)**

Thanks in advance!!

P.S - I dont need this to be done with CSS (even that transition effect)

Comment: that's you want http://jsfiddle.net/aVDgk/3/

Comment: @sandeep I tried this on my  page but it is not working for some reason. Could you please chk this http://jsfiddle.net/aVDgk/4/

Comment: You didn't update the css & mix the jquery. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/aVDgk/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $('.media').mouseenter(function(){
        $('img').hide();
        $('.media').width('25%');
    });
    $('.media').mouseleave(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.media').width('6%');
            setTimeout(function(){$('img').show()},1000);
        },3000);
    });
</script>
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/aVDgk/2/

Comment: Thanks but the main thing is, it should stay for few seconds when mouse out

Comment: Check the above I have made changes,I only add `Settimeout function` to `mouseleave`

Comment: Cant we do that transition in jquery??

Comment: I think if you want the same then its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look on CSS Animations.

Comment: You may post that as a comment, as it is not really an answer.

Comment: @feeela take it easy on him!! He doesn't yet have the option to comment!! :)